# dotnet-ef dbcontext scaffold generates HasColumnType includes length vs HasMaxLength when used with SQLite

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, fluent, scaffolding

TLDR; Microsoft Documentation for [.HasColumnType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.hascolumntype?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalPropertyBuilderExtensions_HasColumnType__1_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_PropertyBuilder___0__System_String_) states "*... should be the complete type name, including precision, scale, length ...*". This seems to be in contradiction to this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224442/what-is-the-proper-usage-of-hascolumntype-and-database-generated) - has the recommended usage changed ?

Using EF Core 3.1 (and 5), SQLite and Northwind database, following examples from [MJPrice Cs8 & .Net Core 3 Chapter14](https://github.com/markjprice/cs8dotnetcore3/tree/master/PracticalApps), I used `dotnet ef scaffold ...` to create similar code and compare to the book. This tool generates a lot of .HasColumnType() methods, and no HasMaxLength() methods.

Is maximum length correctly captured when replacing `.HasMaxLength(15)` with `.HasColumnType("nvarchar(15)")` (example for the CategoryName property of Category) ?

Is .HasColumnType() unnecessary due to the way [SQLite stores types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and therefore only the maximum length information is really needed for this example i.e. database provider is SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you pointed out is for EF Core, whereas the stackoverflow question you linked to is referring to EF 6. As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.stringcolumnconfiguration.hascolumntype?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_ModelConfiguration_Configuration_StringColumnConfiguration_HasColumnType_System_String_), in EF 6 `HasColumnType` expected only the type, without *precision, scale, length, etc...*. So that has changed.

In any case, I don't know much about SQLite so I might be wrong here, but I believe that there is no length restriction at all. Even if you declare a size for TEXT or VARCHAR it will [just ignore it.](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affname)

> Note that numeric arguments in parentheses that following the type name (ex: "VARCHAR(255)") are ignored by SQLite - SQLite does not impose any length restrictions (other than the large global SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH limit) on the length of strings, BLOBs or numeric values.